# Dictionary c тремя параметрами

Tags: c#, .net, словари

В Dictionary очень удобно реализован доступ к данным.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dic.Add("Аналитика,0");
dic.Add("Новости,1");
var temp = dic["Новости"]; // Получаем 1
```

Как сделать чтобы я мог три параметра пихнуть в Dictinary и чтобы также удобно можно было получить доступ к переменным?

```
Dictionary<string,string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string,string, int>();
dic.Add("Аналитика", "analitika",0);
dic.Add("Новости","news",1);
var temp = dic["analitika"];// На выходе 0;Аналитика
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Правильный способ

Объявить новый тип — класс или структуру, — которая содержит значения, которые вы хотите получить по ключу. По вкусу можно добавить `ToString` и прочие методы.

```
class Values
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }

    public Values (int id, string displayName)
    {
         Id = id;
         DisplayName = displayName;
    }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return string.Format("{0};{1}", Id, DisplayName);
    }
}

var dic = new Dictionary<string, Values>();
dic.Add("news", new Values(1, "Новости"));
dic.Add("analitika", new Values(2, "Аналитика"));
Values val = dic["news"];
string str = val.ToString(); // "1;Новости"
```

#### Способ из будущего

В следующей версии C# 7 создание простых типов будет реально простым (синтаксис не окончательный).

```
class Values (int id, string displayName)
{
    public int Id { get; } = id;
    public string DisplayName { get; } = displayName;
}
```

Или даже так:

```
class Values (int Id, string DisplayName);
```

Ну а уже в C# 6 добавление в словарь будет проще за счёт dictionary initializers. Вместо кода выше или этого кода:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, Values> {
    { "news", new Values(1, "Новости") },
    { "analitika", new Values(2, "Аналитика") },
};
```

можно будет писать:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, Values> {
    ["news"] = new Values(1, "Новости"),
    [ "analitika"] = new Values(2, "Аналитика"),
};
```

#### Способ для ленивых

Вместо объявления нового типа можно воспользоваться типом `Tuple`.

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, string>>();
dic.Add("news", Tuple.Create(1, "Новости"));
dic.Add("analitika", Tuple.Create(2, "Аналитика"));
Tuple<int, string> val = dic["news"];
string str = return string.Format("{0};{1}", val.Item0, val.Item1); // "1;Новости"
```